# Shared memory in CUDA is not getting values assigned to it and always prints zero

Tags: cuda, reduction, gpu-shared-memory

This simple reduction function is found in one of the CUDA presentations online.

```
__device__ void reducedSum(double* d_idata, double* d_odata, long LENGTH)
{
    extern __shared__ double sdata[];
    unsigned int tid = threadIdx.x;
    unsigned int i = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

    if (i < LENGTH) {
        sdata[tid] = d_idata[i];
        __syncthreads();

        printf("Kernel sdata : %d \n", sdata[tid]);

        for (unsigned int s = 1; s < blockDim.x; s *= 2)
        {
            if (tid % (2 * s) == 0)
            {
                sdata[tid] += sdata[tid + s];
            }
            __syncthreads();

        }

        if (tid == 0) {
            d_odata[blockIdx.x] = sdata[0];
        }
    }
}
```

But the printf here always prints the following output. What It's expected to do is actually to copy the values from d_idata array and assign it partly to each shared memory block. However it doesn't happen.

[image: console output showing zeros being printed]

Call to the kernel is as follows:

```
long LENGTH = 10;
long N = 5;
int threadsPerBlock = N;
int numBlocks = (threadsPerBlock + LENGTH - 1) / threadsPerBlock;
cudaCalc<<<numBlocks, threadsPerBlock, N*sizeof(double)>>> (d_vec1, d_vec2, d_dotProduct, ....)
```

Now inside the kernel I call this `reducedSum` `__device__` function as follows.

```
__global__ void cudaCalc(int* d_vec1, int* d_vec2, double* d_dotProduct, ... )
{
    int tid_0 = threadIdx.x;
    int index = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
    if (index < LENGTH) {
        d_dotProduct[index] = (double) d_vec1[index] * d_vec2[index];
        d_squared1[index] = (double)d_vec1[index] * d_vec1[index];
        d_squared2[index] = (double)d_vec2[index] * d_vec2[index];
        __syncthreads();
    }
   
    reducedSum(d_squared1, d_squaredSum1, LENGTH);
    reducedSum(d_squared2, d_squaredSum2, LENGTH);
    reducedSum(d_dotProduct, d_dotSum, LENGTH);

}
```

Can some good sir/madam please show me where my code is wrong? If you want to see the rest of the code please request. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fault was with the printf function. I can't believe I spent hours on this.

```
printf("Kernel sdata : %d \n", sdata[tid]);
```

The placeholder is given for integer while the sdata is a double array. The problem solved.

It's such a bummer that *nvcc* compiler doesn't show a warning or an error for this type of mistakes. *gcc* on the other hand shows so many warning. This is should be a suggestion.